# unable to obtain exclusive access to this record or 1 records: 07H7Y000000Cc1RUAS - when running tests

Tags: apex, failing-tests

I'm getting a peculiar error, something I haven't seen before, when I run test classes. *All the failing tests were passing successfully earlier (a week ago).*

`System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: UNABLE_TO_LOCK_ROW, unable to obtain exclusive access to this record or 1 records: 07H7Y000000Cc1RUAS: []`

The 07H prefix refers to ContentFolder.

I get this error on some test classes where I refer to some Content- object. If I run these tests individually, some of them pass while some won't even pass if run them on their own.

I have one Library, which is the standard `Assets Library`. The error happens when I call `insert` on a list of ContentVersion records. I'm running these tests as System Administrator on our sandbox org.

How would I go about debugging this error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: failure occurs while running these tests in production or sandbox/scratch org?

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention: in my sandbox org